# AnkhSVN - How to remove old URLs from list of URLs in the "Open from Subversion" dialog box

Tags: svn, ankhsvn

I work for a small company and am the sole developer using AnkhSVN to version my code.  For the server side I am using VisualSVN v2.5.8.  The server is installed on my own machine (on a different drive).  I have a few repositories that I created about two years ago that have been working fine.

We recently completed an Active Directory Domain Rename (that's another story) so the FQDN of my machine changed so the domain portion is no longer the same as what it was when the server portion was installed.  I managed to get AnkhSVN to connect to the repositories so everything is working again but the URL list that comes up on the "Open from Subversion" dialog box still has all the old URLs.  How can I remove them?  I've searched everywhere I can think of looking for this list but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Chuck R.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that AnkhSVN checks TortoiseSVN's branch of Windows Registry to get list of recent URLs.

I'm able to remove old URLs via cleaning up this branch: `HKEY_USERS\<SID-OF-YOUR-WINDOWS-ACCOUNT>\Software\TortoiseSVN\History\repoURLS`.

Answer (score 1):

I first thought they're stored in the following registry key (for VS 10.0):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\AnkhSVN\AnkhSVN\VisualStudio\10.0\FifoTables\RecentRepositoryUrls
```

but then I checked a little further and they seem to be stored here!

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN\History\repoURLS
```

Comment: AnkhSVN uses both locations, as many users use multiple clients at the same time. The setup experience for AnkhSVN is much nicer if we -by default- show existing locations.

Answer (score 1):

at least as from TortoiseSVN's V1.8 you can clear the url history in SNV settings -> Saved Data -> URL history. Afterwards AnkhSVN shows only active repositories's URLs.